# Maximum number of literal values for SetDelayed?

Tags: function-construction, packages, variable-definitions, assignment

Under what circumstances should I expect *Mathematica* to turn a delayed assignment into an immediate assignment? I have put together a minimal example (available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ft2o44u5qzn4db5/Test2.tgz)) which demonstrates this behavior. There is a package which contains basically the following, where each line has its own cell in the notebook from which the package is generated:

```
setMyVar[a] := (var = 1;)
setMyVar[b] := (var = 2;)
setMyVar[c] := (var = 3;)
setMyVar[d] := (var = 4;)
setMyVar[e] := (var = 5;)
setMyVar[f] := (var = 6;)
setMyVar[g] := (var = 7;)
setMyVar[h] := (var = 8;)
setMyVar[i] := (var = 9;)
setMyVar[j] := (var = 10;)
setMyVar[k] := (var = 11;)
setMyVar[l] := (var = 12;)
setMyVar[m] := (var = 13;)
setMyVar[n] := (var = 14;)
setMyVar[o] := (var = 15;)
setMyVar[p] := (var = 16;)
setMyVar[q] := (var = 17;)
setMyVar[r] := (var = 18;)
setMyVar[s] := (var = 19;)
setMyVar[t] := (var = 20;)
```

When I load this package and then evaluate `Definition[setMyVar]` every assignment is defined as a `Set` rather than a `SetDelayed` in *Mathematica 9.0.0.0*. However if I comment out any three of these, everything returns to being `SetDelayed`. Does anyone have any idea why *Mathematica* would do this? If so, is there a system variable I can change to address this problem? The tarball also contains a notebook which demonstrates the behavior in a setting which is not loaded from a package.

This does not come up if everything is in a single cell, but arranging everything in such a way is not practical for the actual application in which I ran across this. To address why this might be considered to be a problem, I ran across this while using `DistributeDefinitions["Context"]` which as stated in the documentation essentially runs `ParallelEvaluate` on every statement in the context, and this is causing things to be evaluated which should not be.

---

Edit to add: I have confirmed that this occurs with *Mathematica 9.0.1.0* as well. Both machines tested are Linux x86-64.

Comment: I confirm this behavior in *Mathematica* 8.0.4. Undocumented [``Language`ExtendedDefinition`` and ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition``](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20993421/590388) show the same as `Defintion`.

Comment: The question is then whether or not this is an intended behavior, to which I would wager "no." If there is a consensus on that, can this be marked as a bug? I will pass it along to Wolfram, reporting back on whatever I get as a response.

Comment: I just have checked this in *Mathematica* 5.2 and behavior is the same. Looks like a bug to me due to inconsistency with the parallel processing functionality. If you wish to mark it as a bug please include in the question some code demonstrating wrong behavior of `DistributeDefinitions`. It will be interesting to hear the responce from WRI on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you test the code above, i.e. run

```
mySetVar[t]
```

it works correctly (i.e. var is set to 20).

The problem is actually one of "Definition" rather than SetDelayed.  Definition is a weird function that simply prints some info to the screen.  In this case, it gets it wrong, i.e. there is a bug in Definition.  As a work around, if you want authoritative information on a symbol, use

```
DownValues[mySetVar]
```